# Linux: sync/merge two (or more) directories, but keep older file versions?

Tags: linux, backup, sync, rsync

got alotta help throughout the time just by simply scrolling and crawling through the vast landscape of qualified answers here from you, now's the time to ask my first question and it looks rather simple but I've hit the wall.

I want to sync/merge two (or more) folders, containing important files, some pics inside do have exif-data (that Lightroom could read) some don't. I've made backups, in different locations, but was sloppy, and now some files have newer time stamps and/or the creation date of my backup.

Now I want to sort that out, and merge/sync to either a new directory, or into one, containing versions that I do know, have correct (older) time stamps, which I wanna keep obviously.

Went through rsync, tried some old cp-magic, tried to write some commandline script containing diff, du and stuff... I'm exhausted and running out of ideas. ^^

Most of the tools do have "update" functionality, but none has a downgrade option eg. 'keep the older version, if merged and file exists on destination'.

On Mac and Windows, there's 'free file sync', but it doesnt run on my Linux (ext3 files) and through the last years I fell in love with the terminal again. :)

// tl;dr:

So any ideas on how to sync two directories by keeping the older versions, maybe in a new an clean directory (that's just the icing on the cake)?

thx, Bo

Comment: Would it be cheating to "touch" all the files in the old directory so they have a newer timestamp, then use one of the tools that keeps newer versions?

Comment: Well, I don't care for "cheating", I've stumbled upon this old question, which nearly defines the same problem I have: [link](http://superuser.com/questions/570335/what-is-the-best-way-to-merge-two-sets-of-files-but-for-duplicates-to-select-th)